# How to format a date in Ext JS 3?

Tags: date, extjs3, formatdatetime

I have a date value like this ;

```
 Date {Fri Feb 13 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standart Saati)}
```

I get it from a grid column with ;

```
selectionModel.getSelected().data['date'];
```

And column model date format is 'd/m/Y'. It shows in grid well (d/m/Y).But when i get selected value it returns a date format doesn't like 'd/m/Y'. How can i format this date to set to a textfield ?

Comment: So you are basically trying to format Date object?

Comment: Yes. I try to format it to '13/02/2015' and set to a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ExtJs Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Date)

```
var d = new Date(1993, 6, 28, 14, 39, 7);
println(d.toString()); // prints Wed Jul 28 1993 14:39:07 GMT-0600 (PDT)
println(d.toDateString()); // prints Wed Jul 28 1993
```

**Edit:**

Please use `Ext.Date.format` to format the date:

```
Ext.Date.format(d,'d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Can this use in Ext 3? Because returns Ext.date is undefined error.

Comment: `D` should be capital in `Ext.Date`. However, I think it's not going to work as I didn't find `Ext.Date` documentation in Ext 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

According to ExtJS 3.4 Docs Date object is extended with .format() method.
So you should be able to just do

```
var d = new Date();
d.format("d/m/Y");
```